# Eclipse: How to change color of javadoc comment and to remove extra blank

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

In the picture below how can I

1. change the color of comments between /** and */ ( entire thing including *)
2. remove that single black space that I marked in red (before */)

[image: java doc comment color]

Answer (score 0):

1) Look on the appropriate Syntax Coloring preference page.
2) It's part of the vertical ruler, space reserved for the folding controls.

Comment: The Preference is on the Java / Editor / Syntax Coloring page, Javadoc group.